# How to chmod and chown hidden files in Linux?

Tags: linux, chmod, chown

How do I recursively execute `chmod` or `chown` for hidden files?

`sudo chmod -R 775 *` does not work on hidden files.

The same thing goes for `sudo chown -R user:group`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you're okay also chmod'ing the current directory, do that and let `-R` do the heavy lifting. `-R` does not ignore hidden files.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 .
```

Comment: This (`* .*`) is not the safest way to do it. Particularly, it would recurse into parent directory, which means it `chmod`s also siblings of the current directory. The proper way would be `* ..?* .[^.]*` or, even better (considering the wildcards might not match any files) `$(ls -A)`.

Comment: @jpalecek: The output of `ls` is unparseable; trying to parse it is asking for trouble. The proper approach is to use shell globbing.

Comment: Even though in linux you have the ability to change the order of args for chmod, when doing x-plat scripts between linux and OS X, this is the order you should use, e.g., `sudo chmod 775 -R` would go belly-up, so stick to this answer.

Answer (score 40):

`*` doesn't include hidden files by default, but if you're in bash, you can do this with:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

Read more about it in bash's [`builtin` manual](http://dotglob%20If%20set,%20Bash%20includes%20filenames%20beginning%20with%20a%20%60.%27%20in%20the%20results%20of%20filename%20expansion.):

> If set, Bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results of filename expansion.

This will make `*` include hidden files too.

```
chmod -R 775 *
```

Disable it with:

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

Comment: How to do that in `zsh` ?

Comment: You use the `(D)` globbing qualifier, e.g. `chmod -R 775 *(D)`

Answer (score 3):

All files in the current directory, recursively, including hidden files:

```
chmod 755 -R ./* ./.[!.]*
```

All files in the current directory, **not** recursively, including hidden files:

```
chmod 755 ./* ./.[!.]*
```

This will not change an exception filename starting with 2 dots, as example, `"./..thisonescapesunharmed.txt"`

Also, be carefull not to remove the "x" bit, or else all your directories will not be accessible (one needs the x bit to cd into a dir).

Remember this alert: never use bare `*` but `./*` instead.

To avoid problems setting permissions on directories, use `find` instead.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod `VALUE` {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `find` i like it since you can have very fine grained control over it.

```
find <path to start from> -exec chown <options> {} \+

find -path '<path to include>' -exec chown <options> {} \+
```

The only downside is that `find` has different syntax on different versions.